# Compare lists with column in snowflake using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column in my snowflake table that contain values with space

```
    select distinct ("power") from "dev"."devtable"."devschema"
    
    ------------------
     demo1 is good
     what are you doing
     thank you stack
     
   ----------------------
```

but would need to compare with a array of list without space and with quotes and comma :

```
 ["demo1_is_good",
 "thank_you_stack",
 "what_are_you_doing"]
```

I want to use python with snowflake and the purpose of this comparison is to check that e.g. 'demo1_is_good' (column values) is the same as 'demo1 is good' (list values in array) by first removing the quote and looping for each list to compare with the record in the column.

If any of the list is not in the column , then script will exit and not continue.

Comment: Where is the array list stored? Is it another column in another snowflake table (other then devtable) or a variable (dictionary) in python program?

Comment: The array list  will be inside the python script in this format  ["demo1_is_good",
 "thank_you_stack",
 "what_are_you_doing"]

Comment: We are looking at trying to put the other list to another DB as a lookup table but for now the solution is to use the array list inside the python and compare to what is current in the snowflake. for example if the name of one of the value in column has change, then there is no need of proceeding the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code to search string in snowflake table.
Exits when string not found.

```
import snowflake.connector
con = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='username',
    password='password',
    account='account_name.region',
    warehouse='warehouse',
    database='dbname',
    schema='PUBLIC'
)
flag_not_exists = 0
tab_array = []
devarray = ['"demo1_is_good"', '"thank_you_stack"','"what_are_you_doing12"']
try:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select DISTINCT power as col1 from devtable;")
    for col1 in cur:
        tab_array.append(col1[0])
finally:
    con.close()

for col1 in devarray:
    for col2 in tab_array:
        if (col2 == col1.replace('_',' ').replace('"','')):
            flag_not_exists = 0
            break
        else:
            flag_not_exists = 1
            continue
    if (flag_not_exists == 1):
        break
    else:
        print ("Pass")
```

Comment: Great. This is what am looking for. Thanks